# Hide bottom border from QtDesigner designed UI

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have created a very simple UI with the QtDesigner (using pyqt5) and everything is ok except that there is a non-usable whitespace-border on the bottom of it. <

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to remove this border - or write a simple sentence on it (something like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> -> toggle)?

Is the above possible from within the QtDesigner environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the QMainWindow as a window then that blank space is the QStatusBar, if you want to remove it then right click on the window and select "Remove Status Bar":

[image]

If you want to add then you must right click and select "Create Status Bar".